# Natural Language Search on billions of records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, nlp, large-data

I have nearing 2 billion records (search phrases and keywords), which need to be searched using NLS based on an input search phrase. Confronted with this problem I am wondering if MYSQL with scaled-up Read Replicas could be a solution OR if using SOLR or Lucene for Indexing the content, will be more performant solution over MYSQL. Every week we anticipate NEW 0.25 million records to be added to the existing list of (search phrases and keywords).

Currently we have a single MYSQL instance which is an M1 Medium, and that takes around 3 seconds to return an response. We have an option to scale out or even scale up, but wanted to understand if MYSQL is preferred for such volumes or if we should be using something other than MYSQL ? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Using smarter hash as compared to full text indexing would reduce query time. Shard your database by hashes created using NLP techniques, that way your search space is smaller when you fetch the portion that contains high word/phrase similarity scores when you query.

Comment: Thanks Alvas.
Can you please specify some practical implementations of Hashing using NLP?